# How to remove WPCF7 submit button from only specific pages without removing it from others?

Tags: html, wordpress, button, contact-form-7

I'm not a coder, but have been tasked with this project. Our website's theme is from Bootstrap Landkit. On all of our webpages, we use the same template that uses a WPCF7 submit button that scrolls down to a request demo form once clicked. I am trying to either remove this submit button, or at least rename it on a specific webpage I have created without having it altered on our other webpages. Again, I do not know how to code, so any help would be much appreciated! The name of this new webpage I'd like for this button to be removed from is "White Papers." This submit button is found within our header hero-type-writer.php titled "see it in action"

I am able to remove this button all together from every webpage, but I only want it to not show on our "white papers" page.

```
      <a class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-primary ml-1" href="#demo-form-img" target="_self"> See it in Action </a>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6<?= if_present(get_sub_field('column_2_css_class')) ?>"<?= if_attribute_present('data-aos', get_sub_field('animation')) ?> style="background-image: url('<?= get_sub_field('col_2_background')['url'] ?>'); ">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well, we're not a free coding service, so I suggest you do a little learning around your task. See [ask] and show us your attempt.

Comment: Generally, if you're trying to modify a template for one page you'd create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and assign it to that page. It's also possible that you could create another form and customize it, but it's hard to say from what little we know here. FYI, that's not a button. It's an anchor (link) element. It's just _styled_ as a button.

Comment: teh code you're showing is simply an achor button and not a submit button.  When a submit button is clicked it sill submit the entries of the form it is associated with and usually reload the page/form....and not scroll down the page like you describe it.
I think you need to either figure out a little bit more about coding or hire someone who does to solve your issue, it will be faster and cheaper.